# Need help to access my imagick library.. I have the path

Tags: php, imagemagick

Tonight I messaged justhost.com to provide me with the path to the newest version of Imagick they have.

They sent me this:

> Hi,
>
> The latest version which we have is
>   6.4.4.
>
> The path to the ImageMagick is
>   /usr/local/ImageMagick-6.4.4/
>
> Please let me know if you need more
>   help. Thank you.
>   -- Kind regards, Tony Dreyfuss
>
> Just Host www.justhost.com

How do I use it or upgrade my php? 
my `phpinfo();` says I have ImageMagick 6.2.8 10/20/10

Thanks!

Comment: I would imagine there'd be a variable in php.ini for that

Comment: Stack Overflow is not tech support for your webhost. Just ask them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If phpinfo says you have it, and the libraries are installed, then you need to look up the imagemagick functions on php.net. If it's available but not installed as a PHP library, you can (maybe) run it with exec(), depending on the host's settings. If neither of those work, get a better hosting plan!